# WEIRD Django AuthenticationForm Behaviour

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-forms

I have, all day, tried to figure this out but I can't really see where the problem is coming from.

I have a **Django** `AuthenticationForm` that seems to be submitting data somehow but not getting validated.

**forms.py**:

```
class LoginForm(AuthenticationForm):
    username = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'name': 'username'}))
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'name': 'password'}))
```

**views.py**:

```
def index(request):
    template = 'myapp/login.html'
    if request.method == "POST":
        print request.POST #prints QueryDict with its data
        reg = LoginForm(request.POST or None)
        if reg.is_valid():
            return HttpResponse('Success: Form is valid!')              
        else:
            return HttpResponse('Error: Form not valid')

    loginform = LoginForm()
    context = {'loginform':loginform}
    return render(request, template, context)
```

**HTML**:

```
    <form method="post" action=".">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <h2>Sign in</h2>
        <p class="text-danger">{{loginform.errors}}</p>
        {{ loginform.as_p }}    
        <button name = "signin" type="submit" value="0">Sign in</button>
    </form>
```

The `print request.POST` in my views.py prints *QueryDict: {u'username': [u'yax'], u'csrfmiddlewaretoken': [u'r8y1PaVNjxNWypdzP
MaFe1ZL7IkE1O7Hw0yRPQTSipW36z1g7X3vPS5qMMX56byj'], u'password': [u'sdfdsfsddfs']
, u'signin': [u'0']}* but the `reg.is_valid()` keeps returning `false`.

**EDIT**:

I have also tried printing out `reg.errors` but it doesn't print out anything.

Comment: Best way to check what is happening is to print reg.errors after it fails

Comment: @Aquiles it prints out an empty string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try making the following change:

```
reg = LoginForm(data=request.POST)
```

`AuthenticationForm` is slightly different in that it needs the `data` argument.

Also note that you should test it with actually valid username and password combinations (that correspond to an existing user), since `AuthenticationForm` checks for that as well.

Comment: You mean `AuthenticationForm.is_valid()` takes care of `authenticate()`?

Comment: Yes, `AuthenticationForm`'s clean method it calls `authenticate` behind the scenes in order to check that such a user exists.